# ASP Chart's X Axis is wider than the data points

Tags: asp.net

My chart looks like this!

How do I get rid of the empty space either side as indicated by the arrows? The data is dynamically generated from a database.

The x axis is a string, so min / max will not work

[image]
Below is the markup

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTrend" 
                Width="740px">
                <series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="StackedArea" XValueMember="INSPECTION_DATE" 
                        YValueMembers="INUSE">
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartType="StackedArea" XValueMember="INSPECTION_DATE" 
                        YValueMembers="DECOMMISSIONED">
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series3" ChartType="StackedArea" XValueMember="INSPECTION_DATE" 
                        YValueMembers="UNAVAILABLE">
                    </asp:Series>
                </series>
                <chartareas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <AxisX  Interval="1">
                        </AxisX>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </chartareas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `Maximum` and `Minimum` properties in `ChartArea.AxisX`,

Code Sample

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;   // if your minimum X = 0
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 100; // if your maximum X = 100
```

In this way, your chart area will display only the values between `Minimum` and `Maximum`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is to set

```
<axisx IsMarginVisible="False">
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to do following after its rendered on runtime

- Find the minimum and maximum on x-axis
- Update AxisX properties later to adjust axis after data has been plotted from server dynamically. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you paste what kind of string is it. axis should have values or min max and interval defined to create it.

Comment: There should be a property on x-axis to obtain minimum or start and similarly maximum or end. Then you can find the minimum on your obtained data and maximum on your obtained data. Next thing is to check if it matches or not, if both are same that means no spaces on the side. If not then change AxisX minimum and maximum to be same as your data.

Comment: You can see the type of string in chart picture I posted?

Comment: I think that only works when you are talking about data types such as number, dates etc. This is a formatting issue

Comment: Assume your data is loaded at very end when DOM is being rendered and fully loaded. Then you can run JS to obtain Axis Object and manipulate it via https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axisx(v=vs.110).aspx is this not what you are looking for to adjust it after data is loaded.

Comment: The data is fine. The issue is that area chart seems to have padding to the left and right